GPU not working with WSL 2 running Ubuntu 22.04
I had an issue with my computer and had to completely reinstall windows on my machine. I previously had CUDA working with WSL and could run PyTorch models using my GPU. However it seems that WSL can't find the GPU anymore, and I am not sure why. Running nvidia-smi in powershell shows the GPU, but I can't even get nvidia-smi to run properly in WSL.
I am running Windows 10 Pro v 22H2 Build 19045.4780, with Nvidia 2070 Super, with GeForce Game Ready Driver 560.81, and AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Below are outputs from relevant commands in the WSL shell.
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jun_14_16:34:21_PDT_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.6, V12.6.20
Build cuda_12.6.r12.6/compiler.34431801_0

$ lspci
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.

$ nvidia-smi
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390         # version 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-418-server  # version 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450-server  # version 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470         # version 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470-server  # version 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
....

$ ./cuda-samples/Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 100
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL

I have in Windows Features settings: Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform, Windows Powershell 2.0, Windows Subsystem for Linux all turned on.
My only thought is that I need to downgrade the driver version, but I have tried a few previous versions of the driver, as well as using CUDA 11.5 and 11.6.

Taking a guess here based on lspci not working that this is actually WSL1 (see answer), but let me know if I'm off-base here.

If it was just nvidia-smi that was failing, I would agree with your "downgrade" assessment, but that wouldn't cause lspci to fail.
Given its result, my guess is that your Ubuntu is running in WSL1 rather than WSL2. Under a WSL1 distribution I keep around for testing, lscpi gives the exact same message.
You can confirm whether this is the issue using:
wsl.exe -l -v

If that's the case, you could convert the distribution to WSL2 using wsl --set-version <distro_name> 2, but I think I would recommend:
wsl --set-default-version 2

Then delete the existing Ubuntu (wsl --unregister ... -- Warning: destructive command) and reinstall it.
The reason is that the CUDA installation is almost certainly bad if it really was installed in WSL1.  Make sure to follow the CUDA Toolkit on WSL directions.

This solved the problem thank you, for future reference for others, running wsl --version listed WSL version: 2.2.4.0 but its possible I had installed Ubuntu prior to setting wsl to version 2. as wsl -l -v listed NAME Ubuntu-22.04 STATE Running VERSION 1
